# Is it possible to execute a vbproj with mono?

Tags: vb.net, macos, visual-studio, mono

I have to continue a program witch have been coded with Visual Studio and the framework .NET framework 4 but the thing is : I have a macbook.

After many researches I have found that by using Mono it was possible to code in vb.net with a mac. However, the project is working on Windows computer but I get this warning:

```
"warning MSB3256: No assemblies were read in from the redist lists. A TargetFramework profile exclusion list could not be generated."
```

and this error:

```
"error MSB6006: "vbnc.exe" exited with code 1"
```

So I'm guessing that he doesn't recognize that mono should replace .NET framework. I am executing the code with MSbuild, maybe that is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are stuck.

Microsoft would like to bring C#/VB and .NET Core to Mac via Visual Studio for Mac, so you should not attempt to bring any .NET Framework projects to Mac via Mono any more.

This warning is more critical to VB developers, as Mono's VB support (vbnc.exe is Mono VB compiler) is experimental and does not support all VB latest features.

However, for .NET Core development, VB is also not yet ready to be used, and should be available in a few months when Microsoft ships .NET Core 2.0.

You can definitely play with VB by using .NET Core 2.0 Preview build,

https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/05/netcore2preview

But then you cannot use VS for Mac, and have to use an editor such as Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Mono uses `vbnc` by default although there is a Roslyn-based VB compiler built-in to Mono, `vbc`. Interestingly, `vbnc` is even not being installed with `mono-devel` package and it still being used by default.

If you installed `vbnc` and started to get this message:

> "error MSB6006: "vbnc.exe" exited with code 1"

you need to instruct Mono to use `vbc` instead and your code will build. The most reliable way to do it is to set it per project, by adding the following XML to your vbproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VbcToolExe>vbc</VbcToolExe>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The code should be placed inside the root `<Project>` tag.